# Exit from a loop using apply templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have ten elements in my xml as shown below but I need to capture only the first 3 elements using apply templates

```
<name>hello</name>
<name>hello</name>
<name>hello</name>
<name>hello</name>
<name>hello</name>
............
......
```

is there a way to use condition in apply templates to exit the loop after first 3 elements

Comment: You have the answer from @kjhughes, but the meta-answer is that you are thinking much too procedurally. Apply-templates isn't a loop, it's a functional mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than exit a loop, simply `xsl:apply-templates` to the first three `name` elements.

### **Given this input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<names>
  <name>Name 1</name>
  <name>Name 2</name>
  <name>Name 3</name>
  <name>Name 4</name>
  <name>Name 5</name>
</names>
```

### **This XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="names">
    <new_names>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name[position() &lt;= 3]"/>
    </new_names>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <new_name><xsl:value-of select="."/></new_name>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### **Will produce this output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<new_names>
   <new_name>Name 1</new_name>
   <new_name>Name 2</new_name>
   <new_name>Name 3</new_name>
</new_names>
```